# Algorithems and probability related question

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, probability

We are given a function **rand()** that returns a random number from the segment **[0,1]**,

how can we use this function to create a size 100 uniform array,
of **exactly** 50 0′s and 50 1′s.

Comment: Why don't you give it some thought and let us know what you think? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and especially http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Is `rand` returning an integer, 0 or 1, or is it returning a floating point number between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the question, if you want random numbers why does it have to be exactly 50/50, which is the most like outcome. However you can never guarantee it will be 50/50 because this would contradict the idea of randomness.

Simply create and array filling it with 50/50 each and shuffle it with some fancy algorithm, also keep in mind the implementation of randomness isn't random for most programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Create array of size 100, set first 50 elements to 0, next 50 to 1. Then make element swaps `n` times to make it random. For example:
`i = 99 * rand()`, `j = 99 * rand()` and swap this elements `array[i] <--> array[j]`

Comment: That's not not going to give you much randomness, considering that `rand()` returns 1 or 0. So you'll either swap items 99 and 0, or swap nothing at all.

Comment: @JimMischel I suppose `rand()` gives float numbers from 0 to 1